# Configure Remote Address Filter

Tags: tomcat

how can I add an external address (i.e 10.23.45.12) into attributes 'allow':

```
 <filter>
            <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>allow</param-name>
                <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>                   
            </init-param>
        </filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it to the regexp (you need to escape the dots):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|10\.23\.45\.12</param-value>    
</init-param>
```